# Magento 2.3 Disallow Post to /V1/Customers

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, api, rest-api

I am battling spam accounts being generated via Magento's REST API for customers. Someone keeps hitting my site with Postman and dumping in hundreds of fake accounts. I have set Allow Anonymous Guest Access to No. How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /vendor/magento/module-customer/etc/webapi.xml, change the CreateAccount method from "anonymous" to "self"

Save the file and then clear the cache.